# from a single user to multiple users Django app

Tags: python, django, session

i have a chatbot web application that simulate a customer service, where it takes the input and shows the output via request/response and some back-end python files.So far it is working for one user at a time. Now i want it to talk to multiple users at the same time where each user has his/her chatting page and cabot application. i found out that i should use:

1. Django multi-session==> to create a session for each user.
2. Sub-process==> to create a chatbot app of each user session.

The problem i don't know how?!. So,if these any resource to example on how to implement it that will be very helpful.

PS: i'm using Django 10.1,Python3 and new in the Django development field.

thank you,

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to use either django-multi-sessions or subprocess, you may be able to leverage Django's built-in sessions framework to associate chatbot state with individual sessions. You could also use `django.contrib.auth` to associate chatbot state with individual users if you have each user log in. Links below.

Each request/response cycle executes independently of one another. Making some assumptions about how your chatbot works, and that its I/O passes through Django: in your view, first get or initialize the appropriate chatbot state based on the session id or user id, process the input against that state, store the persistent chatbot state for a following request/response cycle, and return the response.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/

http://django-book.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chapter14.html

[Filtering content based on users in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32345380/filtering-content-based-on-users-in-django)

Comment: thank you for the response. Basically, i don't need to login or auth the users.  I want any user to just click the "start chatting" button and talk to the chatbot. Therefore i should use the sessions framework as you suggested.

Comment: may i ask what do you mean by the "chatbot states"?

Comment: By "chatbot states" I mean any data you would need to store related to the specific conversation so that the chatbot can function -- like conversation history.

Comment: last question: do i have to create a new session for each users when the open the chatbot chatting page? then make the chatbot replay to each user request based on the user/session id? because a have to save the conversation to make the chabot remember the questions that have been asked by the user

Comment: That all sounds reasonable, except you shouldn't have to manually create each session. Django will set up the session automatically when a new user visits the page.