# create a chatbot app for each user in django

Tags: python, django

i have a django website that runs a chatbot app to simulate a customer service by getting the question and retrieving the best match reply in the DB using queries.

**view.py:**

```
@csrf_exempt 
def home(request):
    context= locals()
    template= 'home.html'
    return render(request,template,context)
@csrf_exempt 
def male_chatbot(request):
    if not request.session.session_key:
       request.session.create()
    context= locals()
    template= 'male_chatbot.html'
    return render(request,template,context)
@csrf_exempt 
def run_python_male(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
       session_key = request.session.session_key
    param11 = request.POST.get('param1')
    msg = chatbot.run_conversation_male(param11)
    return JsonResponse({ 'msg': msg})
```

**chatbot.py:**

```
raw_chatting_log =[]
chatting_log =[]

 def chatting_log_data(raw_Input,Input,check):
    if check== "check":
       if raw_Input in raw_chatting_log:
        return  True
       else:
        return False
    else:
        if check== "app":
           raw_chatting_log.append(raw_Input)
           chatting_log.append(Input)

  def check_lastB():
      new='جديد'
      if len(raw_chatting_log) == 0:
          return new
      else:
          return raw_chatting_log[-1]

  def delandsave_chat_log():
   name= str(uuid.uuid4())
   thefile = open('/home/mansard/webapps/gadgetron/src/chatting_logs/'+name+'.txt', 'w')
   for item in chatting_log:
    thefile.write("%s\n" % item)
   thefile.close()
   raw_chatting_log.clear() 
   chatting_log.clear()

  def run_conversation_male(user_in):
       last_B = check_lastB() 
       H =  user_in
       NN1= "H:"+str(user_in)
       New_H= ' '.join(PreProcess_text(H))
       if last_B== 'تقييمك للمحادثة و الخدمة؟':
            #do_somthing
       else:
          if chatting_log_data(H,NN1,"check") == True: 
             #do_somthing
          else:
             #find_replay
```

So, the idea is saving the input/output conversation in two list :

1. raw_chatting_log ==> hold the data with out the addition 'H:' or 'B:' just a the input and output.to help the chatbot remembering the asked questions and using it in chatting_log_data(H,NN1,"check").
2. chatting_log=> will hold the the conversation to the chat log in form of 'H:' and 'B:' to save the whole list when the user ends the conversation or close the page in  def delandsave_chat_log()

**and for last_B helps me know what is the chatbot's last responce**

So far it is working for one user, now what i'm thinking is switching to make it  handle or chat with many users at the same time where each user has it own **chatbot.run_conversation_male** and each chat/conversation is separate  each with it own chatting log list so that i can use it for checking and saving the data.

Comment: Take a look at the sessions and auth framework, similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43956826/from-a-single-user-to-multiple-users-django-app/43965777?noredirect=1#comment75217053_43965777